# Storing wmi query in array powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a powershell program to remove a printer. The program prompts for the printer first. I can't get the printers to display separately they all display as one option. 
[image]

```
$installedprinters = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Printer  | Select -    
ExpandProperty Name | ft -HideTableHeaders | Out-String
Write-Host $installedprinters

ForEach($name in ($installedprinters))
  {[void] $objListBox.Items.Add($printer)}
```

Comment: Remove `| ft -HideTableHeaders | Out-String`

Answer (score 0):

Although your code doesn't satisfy [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rules, next code snippet could help:

```
$installedprinters = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Printer
ForEach ( $printer in $installedprinters ) {
    Write-Host ( $printer.Name )
    [void] $objListBox.Items.Add( $printer.Name )
}
```